# Suppose $U$ is open and f is holomorphinc on $U$. Prove $f'(\gamma (t))\gamma ' (t) = \frac{d}{dt} [f_1(\gamma(t))] + i \frac{d}{dt} [f_2(\gamma(t))]$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb C $ is open, $f: U \to C $ is holomorphic on $U$ and $ \gamma : [a,b] \to U $ is a regular path.

How would I prove that:

$$f'(\gamma (t))\gamma ' (t) = \frac{d}{dt} [f_1(\gamma(t))] + i \frac{d}{dt} [f_2(\gamma(t))]$$

So I know that I would need to use the cauchy riemann equations and the fact that $f'(x+iy)=u_x(x,y)+iv(x,y)$,

where $u(x,y):=Re [f(x+iy)]$ and $v(x,y):=Im [f(x+iy)]$ and

$$f_1(z):=Re(f(z))$$

$$f_2(z):= Im(f(z)) $$

I know not how to go further with this, how would I prove this statement?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an application of the chain rule. First note that $f(x+iy) = f_1(x+iy)+if_2(x+iy)$. Then by the chain rule we have:

\begin{align*}f'(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) &= \frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}t} f(\gamma(t))\\
&=\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}\left(f_1(\gamma(t))+if_2(\gamma(t))\right)\end{align*}

Comment: ahh okay thanks. So if that as far as i would need to go? Just showing it is derived from chain rule?

Comment: Yes, this would suffice (well, there's one more step in expanding that last line to get the exact form you were looking for...)

Comment: ah okay great thanks a lot! yeah i can see the last step :) thanks

Comment: just checking, should i do anything with u and v?

Comment: Your $u$ and $v$ here are essentially $f_1$ and $f_2$. It's just that $u, v : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f_1, f_2 : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For example, $u(x,y) = f_1(z)$ where $z = x+iy$.